# Programmatic binding in Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, data-binding

I'm missing the boat on something here, kids.  This keeps rearing its head and I don't know what's going on with it, so I hope my homeys here can help.

When working in Silverlight, when I create bindings in my c# code, they never hold up when the application is running.  The declarative bindings from my xaml seem ok, but I'm doing something wrong when I create my bindings in C#.  I'm hoping that there is something blindingly obvious I'm missing.  Here's a typical binding that gets crushed:

```
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
Binding b = new Binding("FontSize");
b.Source = this;
tb.SetBinding(TextBlock.FontSizeProperty, b);
```

Comment: How do you mean "crushed"? Does the binding just not work at all?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't seem to have any effect at runtime.

Comment: I'm tempted to vote you down for use of the word 'homey'. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like as of Silverlight 3.1, at least, this is no longer an issue.  I can't reproduce it, at any rate.

Comment: I can reproduce something like it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217740/silverlight-4-setbinding-not-working

Answer (score 7):

I've just tried the exact code you just posted and it worked fine, with some changes. I believe the problem is the element you are using for the SetBinding call is not the textblock you want to bind. It should be:

```
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
Binding b = new Binding("FontSize");
b.Source = this;
tb.SetBinding(TextBlock.FontSizeProperty, b);
```

Make sure you also have a FontSize public property of type double on "this". If "this" is a user control, I would recommend renaming the property so you don't hide the inherited member.

Comment: You're right, that was actually just a copy/paste artifact.  In this case, `this` is a custom control and I'm referring to its inherited FontSize property.  I see this happening all over.  I'm afraid it's something I'm doing that actually removes the binding, but I can't identify it.