# Silverlight 4, SetBinding not working

Tags: silverlight, binding, silverlight-4.0

I want to bind the contents of a HyperlinkButton to a resource programmatically, it't not working. This is the code I have so far:

```
        HyperlinkButton Link1 = new HyperlinkButton();
        Link1.Style = Application.Current.Resources["LinkStyle"] as Style;
        Link1.NavigateUri = new Uri("/Home", UriKind.Relative);
        Link1.TargetName = "ContentFrame";
        Binding b = new Binding("TabTitles.HomePageTitle");
        b.Source = this.Resources["ResourceWrapper"];
        Link1.SetBinding(HyperlinkButton.ContentProperty, b);
```

I get a MethodAccessException

Comment: Is "ResourceWrapper" present in Resources? (does this.Resources["ResourceWrapper"]; return an object?)
Is TabTitles.GetHomePageTitle implemented in TabTitles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MethodAccessException` is commonly thrown when the `public` access modifier is missing from a member you want to access.  Have you tested the `TabTitles` property of whatever is held in the "ResourceWrapper" resource?  Have the then tested the `HomePageTitle` property of whatever `TablTitles` returns?

Note also that if `HomePageTitle` returns a `UIElement` you can only place that value once in the visual tree, however my guess is its a string.