# What's the code-behind equivalent of {Binding}?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

What's the code-behind equivalent of this code?

```
<SomeControl SomeProperty="{Binding}"/>
```

(If I wanted to do that in the code-behind of SomeControl instead of in the consumer's XAML.)

That is, how do I construct a Binding object such that I bind directly to the DataContext of my current object, instead of to some property?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatic binding in Silverlight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71932/programmatic-binding-in-silverlight)

Comment: Not quite. I know how to do that. I don't know the syntax for binding directly to DataContext.

Comment: Haven't tried it but since the constructor to Binding just takes the path. Try new Binding(".").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `{Binding}` is just a shortcut for `{Binding Path=.}`, it should be just as simple as

```
SomeControl.SetBinding(SomeControl.SomeProperty, new Binding("."));
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [BindingOperations.SetBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.setbinding%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(myControl, MyControlClass.Property, new Binding(...));
```